# How to insert date type value with slashes instead of dashes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have been trying to insert a value into a date type column with slashes but keep gives me either null(when success) or fail.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists EMPLOYEE (
   id primary key,
   dob Date
)
```

Above is the structure of the table

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, convert(date, "17/12/2015", 103));
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, CAST("15/2/1995" AS DATE));
```

The two lines of code are ones i have tried.
By using the first line, it raises an error.
Second line successfully creates a record but ended up having NULL in the dob column.

I have actually shortened them for readability but if you need anything else i am happy to provide.

Comment: This looks awfully similar to SQL Server, not MySQL, code.  Which database are you actually using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should just use the standard format for date:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (id, dob)
    VALUES (1, '2015-12-17');
```

If you want a different format in MySQL, then use `str_to_date()`:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (id, dob)
    VALUES (1, STR_TO_DATE('17/12/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```

The `CONVERT()` function you are trying to use is a SQL Server extension.  It does not work in other databases (well, apart from Sybase because it is really a Sybase extension and SQL Server is based on that code base).

Comment: How do you know the OP in fact is using MySQL :-) ?

Comment: i appreciate for your opinions, but for some reasons when i use the STR_TO_DATE function i end up having 2015-12-17 value instead of 17/12/2015.

Comment: @William: Which is just another representation of the same thing. You can use `date_format()` to display a date in a certain format, like `date_format(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')` if you're that bound to the non standard representation.